# The contract name 'x.y.IService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'z.t.MyService'

Tags: wcf

I'm working on a very simple WCF service.
At the beginning everything was fine, then I moved the service interface in a separated DLL file.
Since that I got this error:

> The contract name `x.y.IService` could
>   not be found in the list of contracts
>   implemented by the service
>   `z.t.MyService`

My config file looks like this:

```
   <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
         <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
   <service name="z.t.MyService">
      <endpoint address=""  
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
                contract="x.y.IService" />
   </service>
</services>...
```

and my service looks like this:

```
using x.y;

namespace z.y
{
    public class MyService : IService
    {

    }
}
```

Everything else but the service works fine with that namespace.
Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume the z.t.MyService is just a typo?  It should be z.y.MyService

Comment: Thanks Guys. 
The IService interface is typed (like this IService<T> where T : MyClass). 

I wrote a couple of tests and it looks like that the error is there. 

Can't my interface be typed???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine assuming the z.t.MyService is a typo.  This is exactly what we do and everything works for our service.

Edit based on comments:
Yes, the interface can be a generic, however you will need to define the type before using it in the service.

You can do the following

```
public interface IActualService : IService<MyService>
```

Then you just use IAcutalService as the interface for your service.

Comment: Thanks Guys. 
The IService interface is typed (like this IService<T> where T : MyClass). 

I wrote a couple of tests and it looks like that the error is there. 

Can't my interface be typed???